# Ubuntu Server 20.04 can't install packages with exit status 100 during automated `packer` autoinstall

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, system-installation, software-installation

I'm trying to autoinstall Ubuntu Server 20.04 (details below) with `packer` to create a Vagrant box. But I am getting stuck at installing `build-essential`, the shell exiting with status 100. The traceback is
[in the this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffzh2.png).

It seems I [don't have internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bduva.png) altogether.

The configuration I am using is:
`ubuntu2004.pkr.hcl`:

```
source "virtualbox-iso" "autogenerated_1" {
  boot_command            = ["<enter><wait2><enter><wait><f6><esc><wait>", "autoinstall<wait2> ds=nocloud;", "<wait><enter>"]
  boot_wait               = "2s"
  cd_files                = ["./http/user-data", "./http/meta-data"]
  cd_label                = "cidata"
  disk_size               = 8192
  guest_additions_path    = "VBoxGuestAdditions_{{ .Version }}.iso"
  guest_os_type           = "Ubuntu_64"
  headless                = false
  http_directory          = "http"
  iso_checksum            = "sha256:f8e3086f3cea0fb3fefb29937ab5ed9d19e767079633960ccb50e76153effc98"
  iso_urls                = ["https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso"]
  shutdown_command        = "echo 'ubuntu'|sudo -S shutdown -P now"
  ssh_handshake_attempts  = "20"
  ssh_password            = "ubuntu"
  ssh_port                = 22
  ssh_username            = "ubuntu"
  ssh_wait_timeout        = "10000s"
  vboxmanage              = [["modifyvm", "{{ .Name }}", "--memory", "1024"], ["modifyvm", "{{ .Name }}", "--cpus", "1"]]
  virtualbox_version_file = ".vbox_version"
  vm_name                 = "packer-ubuntu-20.04-amd64"
}

build {
  sources = ["source.virtualbox-iso.autogenerated_1"]

  provisioner "shell" {
    scripts = ["scripts/init.sh", "scripts/cleanup.sh"]
  }

  post-processor "vagrant" {
    compression_level = "8"
    output            = "ubuntu-20.04-<no value>.box"
  }
}
```

`user-data`:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_US
  keyboard:
    layout: en
    variant: us
  network:
    network:
      version: 2
      ethernets:
        ens192:
          dhcp4: true
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    username: ubuntu
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
  ssh:
    install-server: yes
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys:
      - ssh-ed25519 <<an-ssh-public-key-I-generated-on-my-desktop-with-ssh-keygen>>
  user-data:
    disable_root: false
  packages:
    - openssh-server
    - build-essential
  late-commands:
    - echo 'ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu
```

Let me know if more information is needed. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

All right, some more digging showed the answer.

I had to change the network adapter from `ens192` to `enp0s3`, which was apparently the adapter the VM was using.

I found it using `ip addr show` from a SSH terminal to the VM during the  installation. I'm still not sure if this is the correct way to do it, since most of my googling showed that people are using `ens192` and apparently works for them. Any opinions are welcome.

Comment: The simplest thing is to remove the `network:` configuration completely.  The default configuration will be used and works for simple setups.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1329971/376778

Comment: Great answer. Just wanted to say that removing the network directive entirely solved it for me. Very good reference in the link!

Comment: @AndrewLowther my configuration never had any network directive at all and I still get this issue. i don't know what I'm doing wrong.